# Как в HttpResponseRedirect reverse_lazy передать get параметры? python django

Tags: python, django

надо передать в `HttpResponseRedirect` параметр `Get` `?model=service`, это можно сделать? или надо через `urls` передавать такое? что не желательно

**views**

```
   def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        formEdit = self.getPostForm()
        if formEdit.is_valid():
            formEdit.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('order_settings'))
```

**urls**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('settings/', SettingsView.as_view(), name='order_settings'),
]
```

Такая ссылка `http://127.0.0.1:8000/orders/settings/edit/?model=service&id=2`

Comment: `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('order_settings') + '?model=service')` например?

Comment: да, помогло, спасибо